# Apache errors give almost no information

Tags: apache-2.4

In my Apache error log (Ubuntu Server 14.0.3), I find many of this error: `sh: 1: convert: not found`. There is no additional information as to what might have caused it. It is caused by the command line application `convert`, which is used by [h5ai](https://larsjung.de/h5ai/).

Usually PHP error logs give good information. Why isn't there more description in this case?

Here's an example of what the log looks like (abridged):

```
tail -n 20 /var/log/apache2/error.log
...
[Mon Nov 16 07:58:07.929839 2015] (Unrelated error)
sh: 1: convert: not found
sh: 1: convert: not found
sh: 1: convert: not found
sh: 1: convert: not found
sh: 1: convert: not found
sh: 1: convert: not found
sh: 1: convert: not found
sh: 1: convert: not found
[Mon Nov 16 08:03:07.945923 2015] (another error)
...
```

Comment: Did you set all logging to maximum verbose? The issue looks like a bad imagemagik install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a short information....

It seems that you apache use some php scripts or something in your site recall convert (it's an image commandline manipulator)
Try to install convert and his related libraries.

```
apt-get install imagemagick
```

check also with aptitude about some php-libraries

Many frameworks use convert to optimize the uploaded images.
I hope it helps!

Comment: This fixed the errors, but I'm still wondering why it gave so little information. Usually it gives a timestamp and the offending file. Is there a reason it didn't ini this case?

Comment: Yes it is... it's 
There is a shell script code (sh) that recall convert then cause an Unrelated error... it's not an apache error then you don't have a comprensive log.